# How to build routes with structs/interfaces?

Tags: go

I saw a method on a blog and decided to try to make it work, so far I have been unsuccessful. I'm trying to make routes with `gorilla/mux` and structs/interfaces. The main problem here is that I can not access the interfaces when the struct is passed as a function parameter.

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    router "routers/web"
)

func main() {
    router.Serve()
}
```

routers/router.go

```
package router

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func Route(path string, ct interface{}) {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    //ct prints {Controller:{ControllerInterfaceGet:<nil>}}

    if c, ok := ct.(ControllerInterfaceGet); ok {
        r.HandleFunc(path, http.HandlerFunc(c.Get)).Methods("GET")
    }
}

func Init() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

routers/web/web.go:

```
package routerweb

import (
    "controllers/web"
    "routers"
)

func Serve() {
    router.Route("/", webtest.TestController{})

    router.Init()
}
```

controllers/controller.go:

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"
)

type Controller struct {
    ControllerInterfaceGet
}

type ControllerInterfaceGet interface {
    Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
}
```

And finally the controller for the specific route:

```
package webtest

import (
    "controllers"
    "net/http"
)

type TestController struct {
    controllers.Controller
}

func (p TestController) Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

I've done some debugging and whenever I try to compile it, it gives me this error:

```
# routers
.\router.go:14:18: undefined: ControllerInterfaceGet
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The document [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) explains some of the concepts you that you may be missing.

Comment: Thanks for the link; yes, I am fairly new to Go. Does not solve my problem though.

Comment: The doc talks directly about how to refer to one package from another package.  You need to import "controllers" in router.go and refer to the interface as `controllers. ControllerInterfaceGet`.  Oh, that's what the answer says.  Is there an error after making this change?

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem that you're running into is that the two are in separate packages. You should refer to it as `controllers.ControllerInterfaceGet`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. This does not solve the undefined error however.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - this does solve the problem!